# Bootstrap Multiselect - Update Dynamically Updated Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two select menus. One has a list of departments with the ID of `department-list` and the other has an ID of `team-list`.

Using [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) on both.

When someone chooses a department, this jQuery is triggered

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getTeamsAll/",
    success: function(data){
        $("#team-list").html(data);
    }
});
```

So, without the plugin, it works as intended, however with the plugin, the team list isn't updated. I've tried using `.multiselect('rebuild')` and `.multiselect('refresh')` to no luck in addition to the above. Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the bootstrap multiselect function again after you append the options to `select`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getTeamsAll/",
    success: function(data){
        $("#team-list").html(data);
        $("#team-list").multiselect('rebuild');
    }
});
```

Comment: The original list remains unfortunately

Comment: Needs testing so will see

Comment: It worked - my problem was I was that I was using the rebuild after the AJAX call which most probably meant the function was being called before the AJAX was done

Comment: yes, @pee2pee JS is asynchronous so it won't wait till the ajax function completes its execution. So yes, the way I mentioned would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `multiselect('dataprovider', data)` to populate options programmatically. ([Docs](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods))

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/getTeamsAll/",
    success: function(data){
        //$("#team-list").html(data);
        $("#team-list").multiselect('dataprovider', data); 
    }
});
```

where `data` is array of objects:

```
var data = [
    {label: 'Option 1', title: 'Option 1', value: '1', selected: true},
    {label: 'Option 2', title: 'Option 2', value: '2'},
    {label: 'Option 3', title: 'Option 3', value: '3'},
    {label: 'Option 4', title: 'Option 4', value: '4'},
    {label: 'Option 5', title: 'Option 5', value: '5'},
];
```

Comment: Thanks - I don't want to have to rewrite my ode to output as JSON at this point but I will consider this approach for the future